# Dynamic physics bodies will not remain stationary

Tags: ios, game-physics, scenekit

for a test, i have created two SCNBox objects, and one SCNFLoor.

I now set scene.physicsWorld.gravity = SCNVector3Make(0,-9.8,0);

I have placed one cube on the floor, and one cube on the top of the other.

All three nodes have zero rotation, and physicsBody.friction values set to 1.0.

I measure the node velocity at 3 points, : didBeginContact, didUpdateContact, and didEndContact. If the linear or angular velocity is not zero i set it to zero, along with the velocityFactor, and AngularVelocityFactor properties of each dynamic node.

Regardless of any of these points, the objects continue to move, (albeit slowly) but the problem is there.

Can someone point me in the right direction, what am i missing ? the documentation states a friction value of 1 will prevent sliding. This is clearly not the case.

I am looking for some coding help where i can either zero the node velocity before its position is updated during each cycle, or prevent the sliding from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was to ensure objects were not moving in the SCNSceneRendererDelegate method :
-(void)renderer:(id)aRenderer updateAtTime:(NSTimeInterval)time
This is pre-physics simulation and you can ensure stationary objects remain stationary this way. Its not ideal but no physics simulator is.

Comment: Can you write a short example of what you're doing inside the updateAtTime? I also can't get that class to be called and I'm setting the delegate.